# Openmp compile Error: 'local_e' not specified in enclosing parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

```
!$omp parallel default(none) shared(mpi, charge, at, e, local_e, virial)
  if (present(e)) private_e = 0.0_dp
  if (present(local_e)) then
     allocate(private_local_e(at%N))
     private_local_e = 0.0_dp
  endif
  if (present(virial)) private_virial = 0.0_dp
```

I am tring to compile openmp with gcc 10.1. However, I got error:local_e not specified in enclosing parallel. I have specified local_e to be shared, but why it is still not specified? I found many people say to remove the default(none) or it is a bug of gcc. But I am afraid if I remove default(none), these varaiable would take some default attributes while shared() still does not work. I think there should have a better way to do this.

Comment: How do you expect us to debug code which we cannot compile? You are asking a question about variable declarations and scope without showing us the variable declarations. From what we can see, the compiler is absolutely right; there is no visible declaration of `local_e`!

Comment: Sorry, here is the declarations: '''real(dp), intent(out), optional :: e, local_e(:)        
 real(dp), intent(out), optional :: virial(3,3)''' .    variables '''e''' and '''virial''' are ok while '''local_e''' gives an error. Is it because '''local_e''' does not have a specific size?  But I just want to declare the data-sharing attributes with shared(). Is it necessary to have a specific size of array before doing this?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't for `private_local_e` (I am still guessing since you haven't given us code to compile), but that seems to me be caught by the `default(none)` clause.